# Kohana 3 - Constructor

Tags: php, authentication, constructor, kohana-3

I attempted to use `public function __construct() { }` but got the error

> ErrorException [ Strict ]: Creating
>   default object from empty value.

The reason behind this is that I use a controller that is protected for logged in users only, I don't want to have to call `$this->protect();` from every action in the controller.

Hence my attempt to use a constructor that calls `$this->protect();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your logged in safeguard in the `before()` method...

```
public function before() {
    parent::before();
    $this->protect();

}
```